# Unable to install Java JDK on Windows via cygwin/ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, java

For testing purposes, I am automating creation of configured EC2 machines. The creation/configuration is done via ssh connection (same logic for various OSs). On windows (Windows 2003 Server), there is cygwin with ssh pre-configured, so that I can ssh there.

As part of the configuration, I need to install given version of Java SDK. I upload the exe installer (jdk-6u34-windows-i586.exe) to the machine and run it with the /s parameter (silent install). When I run this from windows console (in remote desktop) or even via cygwin in remote desktop, it works perfectly. But when I ssh to there and run it in cygwin via ssh, if fails.

The fail seems to be quite strange, since the installer **partially** extracts it's content into `c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\Sun\Java\jdk1.6.0_34` and then it fails with **exit code 67**. The number of files extracted before exit varies.

When doing this programatically using Java and `Jsch`, the command also prints error message `initgroups: Permission denied` to the error stream. I don't see this message when I connect manually via ssh, so I am not sure, if it's related (when googling, I found this error occuring in completely different context, which did not help me).

I would welcome any explanations, why this happens (and how to fix/work around it). Other hints how to reliably automatically install given JDK on EC2 windows machine are welcomed as well. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried without the `/s` (silent mode) parameter? It may provide you with more information to debug the problem.

Comment: Using SSH as a "cross-platform" solution seems kind of weird to me. I would recommend trying out Ant, or some other (e.g. python) scripting tool which is meant to be cross-platform. Cygwin is flaky at best and even states that it isn't an adequate replacement for a shell terminal on a unix machine. Treating it like one will likely cause more troubles than it is worth.

Comment: Good point. When running without the '/s', then the result is the same. 

We don't use ssh/cygwin for real scripting. It's just a way, how to perform some simple tasks - copy files, exec something, etc. on the target machine. If we would use and or python, we would anyway have to start them somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that there is some intentional architectural separation in Windows (from some version), that services can not access UI.

As the cygwin ssh-daemon was running as a service, it could not make UI calls or start UI-based programs. The JDK installer was UI-based (it seemed to do something UI-ish even in silent mode), which got forbidden.

When running the same from Remote Desktop session, it all worked fine, since there the UI was accessible.